# how to make $_SESSION['something'] and adding a $ before it to make it a var. it doesn't work

Tags: php, variables

Hi i need help with a thing.
I defined a session var like so and when i tried to echo the `$_SESSION['lang']` var it just didn't work at all. and of corse i had the `page.php?lang=eng'`

```
    $eng = "This is English. yey";
    if(empty($_GET['lang'])){
    $_SESSION['lang'] = $eng;
}else{
    $_SESSION['lang'] = "$" + $_GET['lang'];
}
```

i guess it was supposed to give me the var `$eng`, that i had defined and still nothing happened. Please help.

Comment: `${$_GET['lang']}`

Comment: and yes of corse i know i had that emty in the if statement, but the else one is the one it interests me(this site wouldn't let me post it without more code -.-).

Comment: Did you make sure to call `session_start()` at the top of your code?

Comment: This will assign the literal string "`$yourgetvariable`" to `$_SESSION['lang']` instead of the variable you defined. You should use the code from @AbraCadaver's answer

Comment: Did you give up or what???

Answer (score 1):

I can't see a very good reason for this but you want [PHP: Variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php):

```
$_SESSION['lang'] = ${$_GET['lang']};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a really bad idea. Variable variables are a good thing but NEVER initialize them from unescaped data. Right now pretty much anyone can set anything in `$_SESSION['lang']` as a value.